# Edit exporter.py file in plugin qgis2web?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, export, qgis2web

I want to change a small piece (a string) of "exporter.py" code in qgis2web Plugin, but when I change and save the .py file on "C:\Users...\python\plugins\qgis2web", changes doesn't apply. I also tried compiling the .py file with OSGeo4W Shell, but changes still doesn't apply.

Answer (score 3):

After you edit exporter.py you should use the "plugin reloader" plugin to reload qgis2web.  The changes should be applied after you reload.

Comment: Or restart QGIS, which also reloads/recompiles the plugin.